# how to extract specific information in cookie in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, data-binding, cookies, authentication

I am a beginner and working on building websites on asp.net platform in visual studio 2008. I have created a basic login system. Now I used cookie to store username in it so that I can use it to access the respective database.

For example. a person with username abc logins. It is redirected to profile page. Now here I want to show his profile details in a list view but could not do. So I thought to use username stored in the cookie to fill the SQL WHERE condition to search the table details of that person and fill it in the LIST VIEW.

So how can I get the cookie information. As I have tried but I access all the information of it at once like "9 may 2011 12:22:20 uid=abc"

If there is another way of showing the information of a particular registered user after he log in then please help me out.

Thanks to U.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your literal question:

```
Response.Cookies("CookieName").Value
```

Remember that the customer can set his cookie as he likes, so this isn't very secure.  An easy fix is to let ASP.NET handle the cookie details.  If you set a variable on the Sesssion, like:

```
Session["UserName"] = "Ani";
```

ASP.NET will send a "session id" cookie to the client, which is secure.  And the user can't change his UserName: it's stored on the server only.

Comment: ok I did set the session id  then how will i extract this 'Ani' username from it so that I can Use it in the SQL String to fill the List View to get details related to ani.

Answer (score 0):

Session["UserName"].ToString() should give you Ani :)